# The name "xxx" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables

Tags: t-sql

I want to separate a table's columns into two set (1st set = bottom 50%, 2nd set = top 50%, there is a reason why I am not using a median formula in this case and I know that there will be a case when the count([ORDINAL_POSITION]) will be an odd number, then I won't get accurate result.) to achieve this I am trying to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, but I can't figure it out why I got the following error message:

The name "sometable" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

```
DECLARE @table2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @table_op_mid INT

SET @table2 = 'sometable'
SELECT @table_op_mid = 'SELECT ROUND(MAX([ORDINAL_POSITION])/2,0) AS OP FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '+@table2+''

PRINT (table_op_mid)
EXEC (@table_op_mid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st problem is that `@table_op_mid` is declared as `INT` instead of `VARCHAR`

2nd problem is that `@table2` need extra quotes when used in `TABLE_NAME` comparision

3rd problem is that `table_op_mid` is missing `@` symbol, should be PRINT(@table_op_mid)

```
DECLARE @table2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @table_op_mid NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @table2 = 'sometable'
SELECT @table_op_mid = 'SELECT ROUND(MAX([ORDINAL_POSITION])/2,0) AS OP FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '''+@table2+''''

PRINT (@table_op_mid)
EXEC (@table_op_mid)
```

**EDIT**

After your comment.. It is the same problem as before.. `@SQL_columnnull_part_2` should be `VARCHAR` instead of `INT`

```
declare @db2 varchar(max) = 'MyDb'
declare @table2 varchar(max) = 'sometable'
declare @SQL_columnnull_part_2 varchar(max) = ''
```

Also, your new query will not work because `STRING_AGG` doesn't add last separator, so you should move the comparision term in the 1st parameter and keep in separator only the `';'`

```
SELECT @SQL_columnnull_part_2 = STRING_AGG(
    'UPDATE ' + @db2 + '.[dbo].' + @table2 + ' WITH (TABLOCK) SET ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,'['']') + ' = NULL WHERE '  + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,'['']') + ' = ''''', 
    '; '
    ) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table2 
AND [ORDINAL_POSITION] > @table_op_mid
```

Comment: @8indie8 and since `ORDINAL_POSITION` and `2` are both integers, the result of the division is an integer also, so `ROUND(n, 0)` returns n, what you meant is `)/2.0, 0)`

Comment: The problem is that when I want to pass the variable's result

`SELECT @SQL_columnnull_part_2 = STRING_AGG(CAST( N' UPDATE '+@db2+'.[dbo].'+@table2+' WITH (TABLOCK) SET ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
 + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,'['']')  + N' = NULL WHERE '
 + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,'['']') ,+ N' = '''';'
) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table2
AND [ORDINAL_POSITION] > @table_op_mid`

I receive this error message: 
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT (ROUND(count(*)/2,0)) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sometable'' to data type int.